# static block and static varibles in java

Tags: java

```
class Person{
    public static String name="Mr.zhang";
    //public static int age;
    static{
        age=20;
        System.out.println("initiate age");
    }
    public static int age;
    public static String address;
    static{
        address="beijing";
        age=34;
    }
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

I define the variable——"age" after its initiation and I find that it works.Both of them are static so why they are not executed according to the sequence of code.

Comment: objects are not initialised in the order of your statements; there are specific rules that the compiler will follow to initialise your object correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you need to think about.

1. The initialization order (the order in which values are assigned to fields)
2. The scope - where in your code can a field by *seen*

If I read your question correctly, you seem to think these two things are the same, but in Java, they are separate.

Although initialization itself is in the order of the source code lines, this does not apply to the *scope* of the field. 
A field is in scope in the entire body of the class, also before it is declared.

(Likewise for a method (or any other type of *member*) - you can invoke a method that has been declared after the point of invocation.)

Because it is in scope (even *before* it is declared), you can assign to the field at any location in the source file. You could declare all your fields at the end of the class file in the source code, and it wouldn't make a difference.

The one point where this can be confusing is when you assign at the same time as you declare the field. Like this:

```
public class Snippet {
    static {
        a = 20;
    }

    private static int a = 10;

    static {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Snippet.a);
    }
}
```

But it's not that confusing - just think of the declaration and the assignment as two separate things - declaration is in scope in the entire class, but assignment is executed in the order of the source code. So `private static int a = 10;` can be seen as:

```
private static int a;
static {
    a = 10;
}
```

To give you a background reference, this is all defined in the Java Language Specification. Specifically, it's in [section 6.3 which defines the scoping rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a
>   class type `C` (§8.1.6) is the entire body of `C`, including any nested
>   type declarations.

Comment: Thank you very much.I try to understand the section but I am a new coder so I can not understand it well----can you explain it in a easier way?

Comment: Just see the JLS reference as extra information - you don't need to understand it to program Java (there are books that explain it much more clearly), but it's useful information when you want to find out some detail that is surprising. I've updated the rest of the answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: You mean the definition(what you mention in the answer as initiation) of a variable can  be placed before the declaration?You know it may disobey the rule.

Comment: I change the position and find it is false.Here are my changed code.

Comment: class Snippet {
 
 static {
        a = 20;
    }

   // private static int a =10;

    static {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
   private static int a =10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Snippet.a);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Block are executed according to the sequence of code (your age will be 34).

Definitions of static field are resolved once at the beginning, so their placement in code doesn't matter. You could place it at the end and it still work ;)

Comment: I know all code related to static field is processed at the beginning.But both of them  belong to the static field.Which of them should be processed first?